# New task added in crontab not run

Tags: linux, cron

At about 8:10 AM, I edited crontab tasks with "crontab -e", added a simple task which should run at 8:20 AM.

```
00 3 * * * sh /home/als6fd/bin/run1.sh
20 8 * * * sh echo "hello">>/home/als6fd/ggfan/1.txt
```

But it did not run at 8:20 AM. What may cause this problem?

If I call "/sbin/service crond reload", an error occurs.

Comment: Show us the crontab row you added

Comment: what is the error on reload?  what does your cronfile look like ?  how do you know the job didnt run? check your local mail and see if there was an error msg emailed to you

Comment: @DavidChan at AM 8:20 I check if /home/als6fd/ggfan/1.txt exists

Comment: Is it a Security Enhanced Linux (SELinux)?  If so, you have to set up a security level for the job.

Comment: @DavidChan can you tell me how to check local mail ?I am new to linux

Comment: @wallyk thanks for your comment. Can you tell me how to check is it a SELinux? I only know it's RedHat

Comment: Try without sh. When I try running "sh echo "hello" I get "sh: Can't open echo"

Comment: @YAMaiDie:  Issue the command `cat /selinux/enforce`:  if it prints a `1`, it is SELinux and enforcing.  If it shows a `0`, it is SELinux but disabled.

Comment: It might also be a timezone issue. Run `date` and double-check the time zone is what you expect. (If not, the way to change it varies from Unix to Unix, but Google will tell you how.)

Answer (score 1):

problem fixed:
as current user does not have right to write to /home/als6fd/ggfan